# Export O365 users with licences, company, job title etc

Tags: powershell, export, office365

i need to export users with several infos, like upn, licence used, company, city.
in each scripts available on internet get-user is used, but i have always the same error in powershell => get-user is not recognized...

i seached, import-module etc. but always the same error, somebody can help me ?

Context:

. windows 10 up to date

. Powershell run in admin

. PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $psversiontable

`Name                          Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.17134.228
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.17134.228
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1'`

. PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> get-module

`ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Binary     2.0.1.16   AzureAD                             {Add-AzureADApplicationOwner, Add-AzureADDeviceRegisteredO...
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     {Add-Computer, Add-Content, Checkpoint-Computer, Clear-Con...
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Add-Member, Add-Type, Clear-Variable, Compare-Object...}
Manifest   1.1.183.17 MSOnline                            {Add-MsolAdministrativeUnitMember, Add-MsolForeignGroupToR...
Binary     1.0.0.1    PackageManagement                   {Find-Package, Find-PackageProvider, Get-Package, Get-Pack...
Script     1.0.0.1    PowerShellGet                       {Find-Command, Find-DscResource, Find-Module, Find-RoleCap...
Script     1.2        PSReadline                          {Get-PSReadlineKeyHandler, Get-PSReadlineOption, Remove-PS...`

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? Office 365 is very similar to OnPrem. Commands are a little different. If you are just starting out I would start with `Connect-MsolService` followed by `Get-MsolUser` . [Here is a guide to get started.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/powershell/getting-started-with-office-365-powershell)

Comment: `Get-User` is Exchange Online cmdlet so you'll have to connect to Exchange Online like [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps). However, for things like licenses you'll need to use `Get-MsolUser` as jrider suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Thx a lot, actually I was missing out the part about PS ExchangeOnline...
So the answer is just:

`$exchangeSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri "https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/" -Credential $credential -Authentication "Basic" -AllowRedirection`

`Import-PSSession $exchangeSession`

and `get-user` is working :)

thx again